# Qt animation without Animation Framework

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, animation

I need to update a QPixmap 1024x128 (math function paints a picture) 30...60 times a second and i don't want to use Animation Framework - i think that is overkill for this purpose. Math function works much faster than 1/60 second and takes constant time to work, so it is not an issue.

Should i use QTimer with 30...60 ticks per second (TPS) and call update() in timer SLOT? But QTimer is not syncronized with actual screen updates and QTimer is inaccurate. My QTimer rate may be too low (not smooth motion) or too high (eat too much CPU) - how to find good one? My experiments showed that i need different QTimer intervals for my linux and windows test machines to get smooth update: linux: 30 TPS, windows: 50...60 TPS (i see rugged motion if i set 1000/30 msec).

Or maybe i mis-understood Animation Framework and actually it is very simple and appropriate for this task?

Comment: Qt isn't really good for something Like that. For smooth results, try Qt 5.1, QML and preferably calculate the image With a shader program (GPU). I think that's Your best bet at getting smooth 60fps With Qt. Or just settle for What You get With QTimer at some suitable interval: not totally smooth but probably ok for a desktop application...

Answer (score 1):

Long shot, but with ruling out the animation framework you don't leave us many options. One idea, which only works, if your math function can calculate all frames beforehand, is to greate an animated gif or mng on the fly and play this with QMovie. But from the overhead, I am not sure that is is better than the animation framework.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the Animation Framework to do any animation, but it is one option that may be of use to you.

It sounds like you think the QTimer should be synchronised to the paint event, but actually it  doesn't matter.

If you imagine an object is to travel from A to B. Many people when starting to animate something like this for the first time, without the framework, would simply have an update function and do something like this: -

```
QPoint pos(pObject->getPos()); // get the current position
pObject->setPos(pos + QPoint(2, 0); // set the position to previous + 2;
```

In this situation, the update of the object is dependent on how quickly the computer will run; the faster the machine, the quicker the object will move, regardless of the render frame rate

To fix this, so that the object moves at the same rate, regardless of the computational power of the machine, the update function needs to consider the time since the last update and factor that in: -

```
QPoint updateSpeed(30,0); // speed at which the object will move
int deltaTime = m_timer.elapsed(); // how long since we last updated

QPoint newPos = pObject->getPos() + QPoint(updateSpeed.X() * deltaTime, updateSpeed.Y());
pObject->setPos(newPos);
```

So, now that the object's animation is reliant on time, regardless of the speed at which the renderer draws the object, it will always run at the same rate. On a slow machine the elapsed time between updates is greater, so the distance the object moves is further between updates, compared with a faster machine. Two machines running at different speeds will preserve the object's movement to be the same distance in the same amount of time.

Going back to your question, you said you're calculating the image from a math function, so long as the image is updated according to time, in the same way that the animated object in the above example is animated, then you just need a timer to call the update() function on the QPixmap at 30 or 60 frames per second, and there is no need to link it to the updating of the calculation of image data.

Finally, if this is not answering your question, as I understand it, please post an example of how the QPixmap data is being generated.

Comment: **On a slow machine the elapsed time between updates is greater, so the distance of the object is updated further between updates, compared with a faster machine** And wouldn't this cause in extreme cases a choppy movement effect?

Comment: @Greenflow, you're right, you would see the object jump if the machine couldn't keep up. That's the same lag that you get when playing networked video games, but it's how animation should be done, based on time and not a fixed amount. All moving objects travel a distance based on time, that shouldn't change due to how we observe a moving object. If I watch you run at a constant pace and close my eyes for a second, you're not going to be in the last place I saw you when I next open my eyes.

Comment: @Merlin069 not very relevant to my question. Because QTimer interface works with milliseconds and have machine-speed-dependent code incapsulated, so i don't have to think about fast-slow issues you explained. I updated my question and created new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528300/choppy-scrolling-of-qpixmap-using-qt-animation-framework

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I'll take a look at the other question.